# Flutter & Firebase Updating documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

is there any way to **update** a field in a certain **document** when **another** **document** is **updated**!!

i have collection "**Users**" that hold users informations such as (Name, photoUrl...). and a collection "**ChatsInfo**" that hold the peer informations(Name, photoUrl...etc).

> **Alice** is the user and **Bob** is the peer.

Alice has a **document** that contains **Bob's information** (Name, photoUrl...) stored in (***Users/AliceDoc/ChatsInfo***). now if Bob decided to **update** his **profile pic** which reside in a document inside **Users collection**. How do i make sure that Alice **peer document** which reside in a document in side **ChatsInfo collection** will get **updated** too!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do with with a Firestore trigger running in Cloud Functions.  I suggest looking into that.  Please read from the documentation:

- [Extend Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions)
- [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)
- [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)